# Reading a continuous input terminating at a condition

Tags: haskell

I am totally new to Haskell. I am writing code to accept a series of values.

```
eg.
1 2
3 4
0 0
```

The last condition in when the input stops and I should display the values 1 2 3 4.

I have done the following, but it doesn't work. I need some help.

```
main = myLoop

myLoop = do inp <- getLine
            if (inp == "0 0") then
                putStrLn "END"
            else do putStrLn(inp)
                      myLoop
```

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "it doesn't work." Do you get a compile error?

Comment: No. I do not get a compile error. I cannot find any way to do this. Can you please help me?

Comment: Then what output do you get with your example input file? And what output do you want? When I run your program I get 3 lines of output: `1 2` on the first line, `3 4` on the second line and `END` on the third line.

Comment: My desired output would be `1 2 3 4` after `0 0` and not after every `Enter` press

Comment: Are you really asking for a way to read in a list of numbers? I.e. a function `readNums :: IO [Int]` ?

Comment: Yes, but the output should appear after the terminating condition viz `0 0` and not anywhere in between

Comment: Your code is semantically correct, but contains a(t least one) syntax error (indendation of `myLoop` recursive call).

Comment: But it does not give the correct result. Let me try to explain. When I execute the code, it prompts for input; I enter `1 2` and then press `Return`. It displays `1 2` which is what I do not want. When I enter `0 0` and press the `return` key, that is when the entire string `1 2` should appear. Maybe I am trying something which is impossible to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are not using tabs in your source. In order to get your example to work I had to line up the `putStrLn` and the `myLoop` like this:

```
myLoop = do inp <- getLine
            if (inp == "0 0") then
                putStrLn "END"
            else do putStrLn(inp)
                    myLoop
               --   ^ note putStrLn and myLoop are at the same column
```

Secondly, I'll answer the question assuming you want to read in a list of numbers / words.

```
readNums :: IO [String]
readNums = do
  x <- getLine
  if x == "0 0"
    then return []
    else do xs <- readNums
            return (words x ++ xs)
```

Example usage:

```
main = do nums <- readNums
          print nums
```

Comment: Added example usage. You get a list back, so you can do whatever you want with it.